# Nginx HTTPS when only matching admin subfolder

Tags: regex, ssl, https, nginx, regex-negation

I have managed to get all /admin requests redirected to https by:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    location /admin {
        rewrite ^ https://$server_name$request_uri?$args permanent;
    }
}
```

But non /admin https requests need redirecting back to http. The following code does kinda work redirectwise but /admin returns a 404. What is needed within the empty block to keep nginx happy?

```
server {
    listen       443;
    server_name  mywebsite.local.com;

    ssl                  on;
    ssl_certificate      /opt/nginx/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  /opt/nginx/host.key;

    ssl_session_timeout  5m;

    ssl_protocols  SSLv2 SSLv3 TLSv1;
    ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;

    root /Users/me/Sites/website/public;

    location /admin {
        # here is your configuration for admin requests
        # don't forget to set "root"
    }

    location / {
        return 301 http://$server_name$request_uri;
    }

    passenger_enabled on;
    rails_env development;
}
```

Error in error.log:

```
12 open() "/Users/me/Sites/website/public/admin" failed (2: No such file or directory),     client: 127.0.0.1, server: something.com, request: "GET /admin HTTP/1.1", host: "something.com"
```

Thanks

Comment: PS, you can't do does not match according to  http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#location. "there is no syntax for NOT matching a regular expression. Instead, match the target regular expression and assign an empty block, then use location / to match anything else."

Comment: VBart, I have added my full config. Thanks for taking a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
server {
    listen 80;

    location /admin {
        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
   }

    location / {
        # here is your configuration for non-admin requests
        # don't forget to set "root"
    }
}

server {
    listen 443;

    location /admin {
        # here is your configuration for admin requests
        # don't forget to set "root"
    }

    location / {
        return 301 http://$server_name$request_uri;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi VBart, this is what I initially had but get 404 for /admin URLs. I have set root after listen 443. Any idea what could be causing the 404? Thanks

Comment: The error log should show what is causing this. Did you look at it?

Comment: Okay, I have checked the logs. This is the error. I don't see why Rails isn't accepting /admin as a valid URL and returning 404. ERROR: 12 open() "/Users/me/Sites/website/public/admin" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 127.0.0.1, server: something.com, request: "GET /admin HTTP/1.1", host: "something.com"

Comment: Did you configure Rails in your `location /admin`?

Comment: Probably you need at least `passenger_enabled on;` directive inside the location block.

Answer (score 1):

This would seem to work:

```
    if ($request_uri !~* ^/admin)
    {
        rewrite ^ http://$server_name$request_uri?$args permanent;
    }
```

Does anyone have a better way?

Comment: You just fall into one of the pitfalls.
http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls